# How can I accept uppercase letters in my prompt? JS

Tags: javascript, capitalization

I would like to know how to accept uppercase B, O, and H for the newBase prompt. I know about .toUpperCase but I was wondering where to actually add it or if UpperCase will actually help me in this case. I know I can also manually place the capital letters in my while test but that is too much code. 
Thanks, I hope to hear from someone soon.

```
var integer = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number:");  

    while (!(integer > 0 )){
    var integer = prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number:");  
    }

var newBase = prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal, or h for hexadecimal:");
    while (!(newBase === "b" || newBase === "o" || newBase === "h")) {
    var newBase = prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal, or h for      hexadecimal:")
    }
alert("AYE");
</script>
```

Comment: If you're trying to cut back on code, you can rework those comparisons into something like: `while (["b","B","o","O","h","H"].indexOf(newBase) < 0)` - sometimes if you think backwards you can do the same thing in a more concise way. But I like Dalorzo's solution better for this particular issue.

Comment: @JoeEnos , Thanks this helps a lot, but what does the < 0 help with ?

Comment: indexOf is zero-based on which position it finds a match. If there is no match, it returns -1. So you could say ===-1 instead, but I generally do <0 for no match and >=0 if I want a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about regex like : `/^[boh]$/i.test("b") //returns true with both B or b and false with any other letter`

For your example: `/^[boh]$/i.test(newBase)`

- **`[boh]`** are the accepted letters
- *`i`* is a modifier to make them case insensitive

**Update:**

- @Oka correctly pointed out that better is to add the `^ $` to indicate that the expression only will accept one character.

Comment: `/[boh]/i.test("Oh, boy.")` => `true`. Probably  want `/^[boh]$/i`.

Comment: @Oka I think you are right that is more appropriate.